# Battery stops getting charged after 15-20 minutes of driving

Tags: battery, alternator, charging

I've got a 1998 Mitsubishi L200 pickup that has a charging problem.

When I start the engine the indicator shows that battery is charging but after driving for 15 or 20 minutes it stops charging. I've got this problem for so long now.

I have changed the alternator, put in a new battery and I'm still stuck with the same problem. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What are you considering "not charging"? What are the voltage readings when you believe it's charging and when you believe it isn't charging? Usually the dash gauge is just an indicator and doesn't give you a very accurate reading. Taking the reading directly from the battery with a DMM should give you a much better idea of what's going on with the charging system.

Comment: What indicator is showing you that the battery is charging? Some older vehicles have ammeters instead of voltmeters, but a google search of your vehicle shows a dash without either.

Answer (score 2):

If the battery does not go flat over time, then this is normal - the battery is charged at a higher rate initially and as it reaches full charge the rate drops off.

The alternator has to then provide a low top-up charge and supply all the other items consuming electricity.

The alternator does not provide its full capacity at all times - only as and when necessary.

Comment: yes the battery goes flat sometime and I can't start the engine .. I cannot drive at night because of this problem..      "excuse for my English"

Answer (score 1):

You've got a 'parasite' that's draining the battery and this needs to be checked out by a vehicle electrical specialist. If you are using a very high rated AH battery, (100AH rather then 60AH) for which your vehicle was not rated for, this will cause the alternator to 'overcharge' the battery as the high rated battery will take all and more power from the alternator to keep it 'topped up' and no power is then available for the vehicle, and it will drain all the power.
Also have your ECU checked out as it may need re-mapping as an over rated battery may have caused an issue.